# Permission.objects.get() method is not working while creating the test database for Unit tests in Django

Tags: django, django-permissions, django-tests, django-unittest

> I Written the Django signals for creating the groups and assign permissions to theses groups for the different user roles but when I am running my test cases then I am getting permission error for creating test database.

```
signal.py

from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission, Group

def create_group():
    permission = Permission.objects.get(codename=codename, contant_type=contant_type)
```

> This is working fine for me when I run my migrations but when I am trying to run my test cases then I ma getting error for creating test database.

```
django.contrib.auth.models.DoesNotExist: Permission matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: where create operation?

Comment: While creating the test database for unit test it throwing above error..

Comment: add unit test code part

Comment: Soory but I am getting this issue while it creating a test database to run the unit test. I written a migration file to create a groups and permissions but when this migration is running for creating a test database then It throwing above error.